# Python 3 save string with hex escape codes as jpg

Tags: python, encoding

How can I save string `s` got in this way:

```
f = open("a.jpg", "rb")
b = f.read()
s = str(b)[2:-1]
```

as .jpg file? In other program I have only `s` like form of this image, so it is: `"\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0..."`.

Comment: `str(b)` will return the string representation of the bytes in `b`, which will look like `"b'\\x06'"`. Why are you converting `bytes` to its string representation in this way?

Comment: what is `[2:-1]` for?

Comment: please explain your real goal. like @ForceBru I don't really understand what you try to achieve.

a jpeg file is a sequence of bytes.

str(b) gives you a string representation of this bytes. a presentation, that can be visualized on a terminal.

Do you have a broken program, that you cannot fix, that is providing the contents of a jpeg file in string representation.

Comment: this code is only to show form of string which I want convert to jpg. my goal is to somehow convert string like `"\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0..."` into form which I can write to file and later open it as jpg image

Comment: A jpg file is binary, it's very unlikely you really want to convert it to a string.  Again, tell us what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: guessing only, but I have the impression, that some existing code returns a string representing the bytes, that represent the contents of a jpeg file and that the OP is asking how such a string from which the leading `b'` and the trailing `'` has been stripped off, could be converted back to bytes.

I thinkg the problem should be solved at the source, but I gave an answer with these assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to change the code, that creates the string in this strange way.

If not possible:

Where is this string coming from? Is this a trusted source or is it coming from a web server or a person who might want to hack / break your computer?

Is the string really created with `str(b)[2:-1]` or is this just an approximation of the real problem?

I am asking, as this is making things a little more complicated then necessary. (It requires adding a `try` / `except`)

Following code should work:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def stripped_str_b_to_bytes(s):
    try:
        return literal_eval("b'" + s + "'")
    except SyntaxError:
        return literal_eval('b"' + s + '"')


testvalues = [
    b"A'B",
    b'A"B',
    bytes([v for v in range(256)]),
    ]

for b in testvalues:
    print("testing with ", b)
    s = b[2:-1]
    print("S =", s)
    c = stripped_str_b_to_bytes(s)
    assert b == c
```

It tries to prepend `b'` and append `'` to `s` and evaluate that string as a python expression.

If this doesn't work, then it tries to prepend `b"` and append `"` to `s` and evaluate it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! String `"\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0..."` is beginning of `str(b)[2:-1]` as `b` is bytes form of 1x1 violet pixel saved in `a.jpg`.